# how to link to a div without #

Tags: php, html, ajax, .htaccess

I currently have a responsive website design that has all the content in index.php and only shows the selected div according to which page is being viewed. The menu tabs are just link to the different "pages" (div's) as #blog for example.

I would like to have "Real" links to each separate page so i can have www.example.com/blog link directly to my blog instead of www.example.com/#blog

.htaccess? ajax? separate all my content into their own .html and have index.php load them according to whichever page is requested?

Answer (score 1):

[pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method) or [replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method) is what you want. Then once you have that you will also need to [route all the requests to your main page through .htaccess](http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2012/code/htaccess-for-html5-history-pushstate-url-routing/#give-me-teh-code) and then pick them up after the page is loaded.

Comment: i had not seen these before but after a quick read through it seems they are more intended towards allowing for the back button to be clicked and go to the previous page. Not what i am looking for but thank you, could come in handy as back button doesn't work "properly" right now either.

Comment: No, it's for changing the URL without reloading the page. Look it up on the web for tutorials: http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2012/code/htaccess-for-html5-history-pushstate-url-routing/